# jQuery Custom validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

On the form I need to provide the validation where the validation depends on the value of two fields, but I can not seem to get it to work.

```
$.validator.addMethod("validateTask",function (value, element, params) {
        if (($("#ID").val() == 1) && ($("#IDName").val() == 0)) {

                return  "required";


            }
    }, 'Enter an individual.');
```

and the call is

```
Name:{
        validateTask: true
    }
```

Comment: What behavior are you expecting?  What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: validation method needs to return boolean

Comment: it should change the color to red but that done through css

Comment: Use `return true`, not `return  "required"`

Comment: Show us the rest of your code.  Is `.validate()` enclosed within a handler?  If so, that's totally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the plugin docs, it appears all you need is a **[required dependency callback](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-callback)**

```
$(selector).validate({    
    rules:{
       Name:{
           required: function(element){
            return $("#ID").val() == 1 && $("#IDName").val() == 0;
       }
    },
    messages:{
        Name:{ required: 'Enter an individual.'}
    }
})
```

Comment: it does not work first time around it only works once I come back to the form

Comment: if it works once, my code is correct, you likely aren't implementing it properly..within ready handler, not within any other handlers

Comment: Very good point @charlietfl... it seems like a lot of people lately think putting `.validate()` within a click or submit handler is how it's done.  It's just so obviously wrong.